# Problem with delete rows from table using @tanstack/react-table

Tags: reactjs, delete-row, react-table, react-table-v8

I create my custom AppTable component with @tanstack/react-table. Then in parent component i want add button which will trigger delete checked rows in my AppTable component. For that i declare selected state in parent component and pass setSelected function as callback to update state after any row checked in AppTable component.
The problem happens when I try to delete any row. I can't cause a state change in a child component AppTable  from a parent component. In @tanstack/react-table for row selected API use rowSelected state which consists of internal ids of checked rows. For delete I need original Ids from data array.

Example in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tanstack-problem-with-delete-row-qme1s5). You can try delete last row and you will see that in header checkbox will still checked. You can try delete row in middle and you will see that next row will have checked state.

Please suggest how to implement the removal of rows from the AppTable component, if the button for deletion is outside this component. After deleting rows, the state of checked rows should be empty

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can do it.
Follow the code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tanstack-problem-with-delete-row-forked-f8rpkw?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: That sandbox doesn't even work.  There are items that remain checked after deleting.  Also, please show code and an explanation.  I've ran into way too many code sandboxes recently that no longer work.

Comment: The sandbox is working. 
If you select all and click delete, first item will removed, all items will remain checked. 
But, if you select a single item , the item will  removed from the list, no items will remain checked.

Comment: But if I delete the item that is checked, nothing else should be checked.

Comment: Please follow the https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/features/row-selection#resetrowselection. You can use the ` table.resetRowSelection();` and please do not depend on sandbox code. It was just for some others demonstration purpose.